# How to make the data return 0 when using UNION ALL?

Tags: mysql, join, count, frequency

When using UNION ALL,the data will not return 0. For example, if the frequency for high in table score is zero, it will return nothing. That is why I want to apply outer join in my code

**Table1**

```
  id    |   myid     |    score       |
---------------------------------------
1       |    20      |    high        |
2       |    20      |    low         |
3       |    21      |    average        |
4       |    21      |    high        |
5       |    21      |    low         |
```

**Table2**

```
 id2    |   myid     |   score      |
-------------------------------------
1       |    21      |   high       |
2       |    21      |   low        |
3       |    20      |   low        |
4       |    20      |   low        |
5       |    20      |   low        |
```

**The output that I got for myid=20**

```
myid     |  score       | f  |
-------------------------------
 20      |   low        | 4   |
 20      |   high       | 1   |
```

**Desired output**

```
 myid    |  score       | f  |
-------------------------------
 20      |   low        | 4   |
 20      |   high       | 1   |  
 20      |   average    | 0   |
```

**My code:**

```
select myid, score, count(*) as f
from
(
  select myid, score from table1 where myid=12
  union all
  select myid, score from table2 where myid=12
) unioned
group by myid, score
```

Comment: `JOIN` = horizontal conjunction, `UNION` = appending data vertically - `GROUP BY` and aggregations generally work vertically.

Comment: U mean that I should use union?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UNION ALL` query is not enough because it may not contain all the possible values of `score`: `'high'`, `'low'` and `'average'`.
Use a query that returns all these possible values and left join the `UNION ALL` query:

```
select s.score, count(t.score) f
from (select 'high' score union all select 'low' union all select 'average') s
left join (
  select * from Table1 where myid = 20
  union all
  select * from Table2 where myid = 20
) t on t.score = s.score
group by s.score
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6d9fc215565f51af8b0c80f190dcbb75).
Results:

```
> score   |  f
> :------ | -:
> average |  0
> high    |  1
> low     |  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a union of the two tables, and then aggregate on that:

```
SELECT
    myid,
    score,
    COUNT(*) AS f
FROM
(
    SELECT myid, score FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT myid, score FROM table2
) t
GROUP BY
    myid,
    score;
```

Comment: If I use union, it will not return 0 for selected score

Comment: @huhu My answer should actually work with the sample data you did provide.  Can you provide other data which reveals a problem with my answer?

Comment: Your method is working well, but it will not return 0 if the data, likes `low` is zero or not occupied

Answer (score -1):

You can use `UNION` both tables, and then `GROUP BY` myid. For example:

```
select
  myid, score, count(*) as f
from (
  select myid, score from table1
  union all
  select myid, score from table2
) x
group by myid, score
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to always show `high` and `low` values as zero in the absence of rows for them, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` to do it:

```
select myid, score, sum(c) as f
from (
  select 'low' as score union select 'high'
) s
left join (
  select myid, score, 1 as c from table1
  union all
  select myid, score, 1 from table2
) x on x.score = s.score
group by myid, score
```

Mind I didn't test this last query.

Comment: I have tried these method before, but,example: if the frequency for `high` is zero. It will not return the value? Do u have suggestion?

Comment: I added an extra query that might be what you need. Your sample data does not show the case you are asking about, though. I would suggest you add the case to the question in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: ....I already edited my question....sorry...I also confuse with my question